# Mysql, is there a way to know which conditions return true in a multiple condition WHERE?

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, where-clause

In example

SELECT * FROM users  WHERE first_name LIKE '%a%' OR last_name LIKE '%a%';

I need to know which one returned true?

I know I can run separate queries, but is there a more optimal way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this, which implements a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname,
  case 
    when firstname LIKE '%a%' then 'firstname match' 
    when lastname LIKE '%a%' then 'last name match'
    else null
    end matchedcol
FROM users 
WHERE firstname LIKE '%a%' OR lastname LIKE '%a%';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b074e/4)

Comment: I guess as Reza Sanaie suggested I can have a "case" per column since I will need to use the "else" per column too, thanks for your help.

Comment: @EduardoValenzuela yes, if you have several columns that you want to return, then you would need to expand the `CASE` statement

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your query like this:
`SELECT *,CASE WHEN <condition 1> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Cond1, .... FROM ...` and check on that column name value